# Is there a safe way to redirect url via user input?

Tags: javascript

Before asking question, let me explain what I want to make.

I wanted to get user's GET input for rewriting the url.
Normally, if it were form using 'GET', user would get the url like this;
http://example.com/search?q=user_input 
 (q is the name of the form.)

But I want

http://example.com/search/user_input

..

So I coded

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener.('submit', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();
location.href = "/search/" + this.elementes.q.value;
});
```

then I thought it may be dangerous.

Is there a safe way to rewrite url via user input?

Is it helpful to use regexp or something else written in Javascript?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: What do you mean by *dangerous*? What are you concerned about?

Comment: The effect of setting location.href is the same as user wrote an URL to the address bar. You can't control the latter, why to bother to control the former either?